# Time Complexity of two codes

Tags: c++, time

What makes the first code faster than the second?
*I tried those 2 codes one gave me a Time limit that exceeded 1000 ms and the other works on 140ms* at a long test input of CodeForces test

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n, m, a, l, r, c(0), d(0);
scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
while (n--)
{
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if (a == 1)
    {
        c += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        d += 1;
    }
}
int up = min(c, d) * 2;
while (m--)
{
    scanf("%d%d", &l, &r);
    printf((r - l) % 2 == 1 && r - l < up ? "1\n" : "0\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

the slow one is:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
int main()
{
int n, ones{}, _ones{}, l, r, q, temp;
std::cin >> n >> q;
while(n--)
{
    std::cin >> temp;
    if(temp == 1)
        ones++;
    else
        _ones++;
}
int common = std::min(ones, _ones) * 2;
while(q--)
{
    std::cin >> l >> r;
    std::cout << ((r - l) % 2 == 1 && r - l < common ? "1\n" : "0\n");
}
}
```

Comment: The time complexity is the same, as the algorithm is identical. Now, C++ streams are notably slower than C classical I/O, *especially when the synchronization with C I/O is not turned off*.

Comment: Online coding competition sites are no profilers and running a program a single time in an unknown and uncontrollable environment doesn't give meaningfull results. You shouldn't take these numbers too serious.

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095).

Comment: Try the slow code with `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` added to the start of the program to see if that's an I/O issue.

Comment: Cin and cout weren’t built for speed, they were built for flexibility. Generally speaking you can have one or the other.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if library imports/includes are counted, but doing the `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` usually takes a lot of time generally

Might be because of that, maybe include only the ones you need

Comment: Including `<bits/stdc++.h>` might slow *compilation* time, but it shouldn't affect *execution* time, which is what the question is about.